# How can I monitor the traffic on a single port?

Tags: windows, wireshark

I am developing a python messenger client but I feel this is more targeted to superuser than StackOverflow. My server application seems not to get the data sent from time to time, so I want to see what exactly is being sent each time over a specific port such as 42222. I tried wireshark but I am having trouble filtering data on this port specifically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your WireShark solution will work, you just need to use the correct filter:

```
port 42222
```

You may want to read the [WireShark wiki on capture filters](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters), there is an abundance of useful filters you can use.

Comment: if you specify only the source port you won't be able to see replies, and if you only specify dest port you won't see requests

Comment: @nos, ahhh, don't know what I was thinking... You're absolutely right. (To avoid confusion, I removed my earlier comment assuming "that only a local *or* remote port is to be monitored".) By the way: a similar *display* filter would read **`tcp.port eq 42222 or udp.port eq 42222`** (where things like `tcp.dstport` would only show part of the communications, like @nos noted).

Answer (score 2):

Download and run [**Nirsoft's SmartSniff**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) (it's 'portable', so no installation required), press **CTRL + F8** to open the Filter and enter the folowing line:

```
include:local:tcp:42222
```

now adjust the **Options** (e.g. Display Capture Time, Display Outgoing Data, etc.) to your likings. you may create a **HTML report** from the **View** menu.